# what's the featherjs way to handle non-data related actions and child objects?

Tags: conceptual, feathersjs

I just discovered [feathersjs](https://feathersjs.com) and really like the idea behind it, even though I'm still unsure how the service-based philosophy can fit for applications which are more complex than a simple CRUD UI.

In order to better understand it I made up an example: Consider an application where you can create and share surveys. You could easily manage to create a survey *service* to create, update and get the properties of a survey (i.e. questions and answers). But how should one handle the following aspects:

1) There are *actions*, i.e. service invocations which do not affect the data at all. One action could be to send a reminder email to all invited users who did not participate on a survey yet. If not using feathers I would created a dedicated express endpoint for this, but how do those actions fit in the feathers philosophy? Should one create a service (only implementing one HTTP verb) per action? This will get confusing soon. Use *hooks* that detect updates on virtual fields and trigger the action? Hard to document and confusing as well.

2) Imagine users could add comments to a survey. The comments would be part of the survey model (I'd use MongoDB for that, so consider each survey object to have a *comments* array). The client web would invoke the `GET /survey/123` method on the *survey service* which would return the comments amongst the other properties (question, answers, ..). But what about adding comments? Should I use a dedicated service for it, or how would this fit into the *survey* service? How would such a request look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Feathers slack channel: https://feathersjs.slack.com/messages/C0HJE6A65/

Sending an email is fine in a hook. For actions you could do a patch with a certain `action` attribute and then use hooks to determine which action should be performed, etc. The other way would be a simple small service that only has `create` implemented. For comments I would probably have a `comments` or `survey-comments` service and then your `survey/123` could populate the comments. Or the web could make 2 calls, one to fetch the survey, the other to fetch the comments.

Comment: A new community-provided hook may be helpful sending that email async with the DB call. https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-community-hooks/blob/master/src/run-parallel.js

Comment: Thanks for the +50 !